# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in Classipress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm using `Classipress theme` for wordpress, and I'm trying to sticky my featured ads on the on in categories .

I found a code that is return this error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in loop-ad_listing.php on line 26
```

To use the sticky on top code, I had to edit two pages and insert two codes and I'll post the error part:

First: `loop-ad_listing.php`

### Code1:

```
global $postisfeatured;
global $featurePostArray;

if ($postisfeatured == "1") 
    array_push($featurePostArray, $post->ID);

if (in_array($post, "ID", $featurePostArray) && $postisfeatured != "1") 
    echo '<div class="hide">';
```

### Code2:

```
if ($postisfeatured != "1") {
    appthemes_after_endwhile();
    $postisfeatured = "";
}
```

That line: `if (in_array($post,"ID",$featurePostArray) && $postisfeatured != "1") {`
is the error.

Answer (score 7):

the signature for `in_array` looks like:

```
  in_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = FALSE);
```

where:

`needle` is the string,int,resource etc which you're searching for.

`haystack` is the array in which you're searching

`strict` (optional) If (or not) the matched item should be identical (`===`)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using the `in_array` function as it should be used.

In the second parameter you've placed a string (i.e `"ID"`), it's wrong; you should place the array that you wish to search in, at that spot.

The outcome should be something like this:

```
$valueToSearch = "a";
$arrayToSearch = array("a", "b", "c");
echo in_array($valueToSearch, $arrayToSearch);
```

[Please refer to the documentation](http://pk1.php.net/in_array)

Answer (score 2):

You used "ID" as a second parameter which is a string. Try the following:

```
if ( is_array($featurePostArray) && in_array($post->ID, $featurePostArray) ) {
    //some action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this problem. I've got similiar situation in my form field `select multiple` which automatically creates not simple variable but array type variable(PHP weak var types). So when I declared the value at first in my code:

1. `$lang='';`
2. then `$lang=$_POST['lang'];`
3. `<select id="lang" name="lang[]" multiple size="3">
           <option value="en"<?php if(in_array('en',$lang)) echo ' selected';?>>English</option>
           <option value="fr"<?php if(in_array('fr',$lang)) echo ' selected';?>>French</option>
           <option value="pl"<?php if(in_array('pl',$lang)) echo ' selected';?>>Polish</option>
       </select><br>`
4. and then I tried to run script and select none of the option I got known error "in_array() expects parameter 2..."
5. **solution is** to set(**in point 1.**) to empty array `$lang=array();`