# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array in php

Tags: php

I've made an update of my prestashop shop, now I have this error when I try to open the site

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
>   cdesigner.php on line 431

```
line 430:    $str_low = Tools::strtolower($tags_c);
line 431:    if( !empty($str_low) && !in_array($str_low, $tab_tags_image) )
line 432:    $tab_tags_image[] = $str_low;
```

Comment: What does `$tab_tags_image` look like? Have you tried debugging that? Can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in Classipress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437671/in-array-expects-parameter-2-to-be-array-string-given-in-classipress)

Comment: i think you shoyld first define  tab_tags_image  as array

Answer (score 0):

You have to use second argument as an array not string so **$tab_tags_image** should be an array. You need to debug using **var_dump($tab_tags_image);exit;** to know which type of value comes.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I tried to debug using your tip but my site broke down.
Now I have :

JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 202: "2\",\"3\",\"19\",\"782\"]]],
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /home/coeurtech/public_html/modules/cdesigner/cdesigner.php on line 431
JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 209: "2\",\"3\",\"19\",\"782\"]]],JSMin: Unterminated String at byte 991: "2\",\"3\",\"19\",\"782\"]]],

Answer (score 0):

try and replacing the $tab_tags_image with `array($tab_tags_image)`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check using is_array function in php

```
if(is_array(tab_tags_image)) {
  if( !empty($str_low) && !in_array($str_low, $tab_tags_image)) {
   $tab_tags_image[] = $str_low;  
 }
}
```